Uncertain Sankey or tikz style hatch
I'm making use of the Sankey package, but I would like to display uncertainty of the flow. There is some research on this form of display (see doi: 10.1016/j.cola.2019.03.002). I'm picturing hatch marks overlaid on the flow.
As an interface, I picture one or a few extra tikz keywords specifying the uncertainty in either % or absolute value of the flow width. Ideally this could be added somehow to the existing Sankey diagram syntax, without having two add significant extra code, or generate the diagram a 2nd time overlaid on top for example.
For example, with this MWE and output
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{sankey}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{sankeydiagram}[end style=arrow,fill/.style={fill=orange!20,left color=red,right color=blue}]
    \sankeynode{name=foo,quantity=10}
    \sankeynode{name=bar,quantity=10,at={[xshift=-5mm]foo.right}, anchor=left}
    \sankeydubins{foo}{bar}
    \sankeyend{bar}
  \end{sankeydiagram}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Which produces:

I'd like to have something like

Except a nice hatch pattern, not the SprayPaint from my local Paint program in this example.
I'd like to keep it simple, if possible. Something like
    \sankeyadvance[uncertain=940]{b}{3cm} % absolute uncertainty
    % or
    \sankeyadvance[some_color,hatch=0.3]{b}{3cm} % 30 % uncertainty

I've tried experimenting with color fades, but I can't add two fades on top of each other (e.g., \sankeyadvance[fade1-horiz,fade2-vert]{b}{3cm}), and I'm not sure how to make an overlay that is a hatch. The hatch examples in the Sankey documentation (see p.39 at http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/sankey/sankey.pdf#section.12) does not compile on my computer - although all the other examples work.

Can you provide something compilable?

Please don't link to specific CTAN mirrors. Only link to the round-robin. It doesn't make sense for somebody in Europe to visit a US site to get something we can easily get from a closer mirror and mirrors come on and off line etc.

Fixed mirror link. Sorry and thank you for catching that. Updated with MWE. I think this might be fairly easy to do, and likely to better handle the complexity of a full Sankey diagram, by doing it by hand (Inkscape).

The hashes there are using a fairly simple pattern - the lines? When you say about two fadings, what are you trying to get it to look like? The spray paint thing doesn't seem fading like? Sorry, but I don't know anything about these diagrams, so it is a little bit difficult to understand what you want. (For me, that is.)

I have no hash in my figure. By hash I mean x or # pattern, repeating, some width of the arrow, in place of where the spray is. More generally, the arrow width represents something. I'm trying to graphically represent uncertainty of the arrow width. I'm open to suggestions how to do that in as aesthetically pleasing way.

Sorry, by 'the hashes there' I meant in the PDF example you linked in the documentation.  But I also meant 'hatch' and not 'hash'. That diagram includes a line pattern as well as using fading. I was asking if the lines were what you meant by hatching and how that connected to the fading.

Yes, the while crossed lines are what I mean by hatching. They are unconnected to the shading, except that I would like both - so some amount of overlay. I'm using shading differently, more like the arrow example in this post. The actual project is at https://github.com/mankoff/sankey

I got example 4 to compile, complete with the white hatch pattern. It shouldn't (!) be too hard to figure out a way to apply that to your arrow, but I'm not sure what you want done with the fading. Do you want that applied as well as the hatch? And in both directions (?!)? Or do you want it applied at an angle or to somewhere else entirely? If necessary, you can define a custom fading, similar to defining a custom shading.

I can't reproduce the output you show in the question from the code you say produces that output, though. My arrow has no shading and is a pale orangey colour.

Sorry - when I updated the MWE graphic with shading I forgot to update the MWE code. Your example below (will comment there) is great, but I'd need it to handle the full features of the Sankey package - that is, turns and twists generated by \sankeyoutin or \sankeydubins.

Do you want something like this?

Your code didn't produce the shaded arrow you showed to begin with, so I added that. I then added the white hash style from the example you linked to and reduced the opacity slightly.
Note that this works only for a white background. If you use this on a coloured background, it will look very odd indeed.
\documentclass[tikz,11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{sankey}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
\tikzset{%
  white hash/.style={% from example-4 in the docs
    draw=none,fill=none,
    pattern={Lines[angle=60,line width=2pt,distance=4pt]},
    pattern color=white,
  },
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/719842/ addaswyd o gwestiwn mankoff: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/719616/
    \begin{sankeydiagram}[end style=arrow,fill/.style={left color=magenta,right color=blue}]
      \sankeynodeend{name=foo,quantity=10}
      \sankeyadvance*{foo}{2.5cm}
      \draw [white hash,opacity=.75] ([xshift=28.5mm,yshift=-1.5mm]foo.east) rectangle (foo.south west);
    \end{sankeydiagram}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Yes, that's a great example, but it should also support turns and twists generated by \sankeyoutin or \sankeydubins. Also, I don't think this is scaleable if I need to manually adjust this with xshift=28.5mm and etc. I'm generating dozens of complex images, each with the same basic structure but different widths and curves. See https://github.com/mankoff/sankey/issues/16

@mankoff Then you need to provide an MWE in your question which reflects what you actually need an answer to do. The xshift is only for the arrow head. It should be possible to get that coordinate without guessing, but it didn't seem worthwhile for a proof-of-concept.
